# Div with data-position="fixed" and fullscreen

Tags: jquery, html, events, jquery-mobile

For my tablet app, I must have a layer which is `data-position="fixed"`
Automaticaly, an event click on background is added for fullscreen feature
see this example: click anywhere you want; both the header and footer will toggle visibility.

My problem is I do not want this feature but even if I include `data-fullscreen="false"` in my `div`, the event is still created.

I cannot directly add `"position fixed"` in CSS because it completely crashes the display. Have you come across this? How did you deal with it?

Comment: Which example, where is the link?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <div data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-fullscreen="true">
```